# Missing dependencies while loading class file CassandraConnector.class

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to use Cassandra with Spark but when I'm trying to execute some of the methods, I'm getting this kind of error:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using Scala version 2.11.8, Spark version 2.0.0. and Cassandra 3.7.

Comment: Is spark-cassandra connector is in classpath?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: can you try copying spark cassandra connector to lib directory of spark and run the same thing again

Comment: Nah, I tryed in terminal and also in IntelliJ but didn't work. The thing is, I was using Apache Spark 2.0.0.-preview and there is no connector for that version of Spark. I downgraded the Apache Spark, changed **rpc_address** on my server address and the query in Scala passed. Thank you for trying :)